# Leading zero in BigInteger multiplication

Tags: java, biginteger, multiplication

I use simple function to multiply big integers. Sometimes one more leading zero byte is included to output. Why is it happened and how I can prevent it?

PS: a and b are already less than mod

```
private byte[] multiply(final byte[] a, final byte[] b, final BigInteger mod) {
    BigInteger M1 = new BigInteger(1, a);
    BigInteger M2 = new BigInteger(1, b);

    BigInteger out = M1.multiply(M2).mod(mod);

    res = out.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: can you give examples of your inputs and what you are seeing as output? or a working example on ideone.com?

Comment: Yes, sure. I prepared code and you can have a look here [link](http://ideone.com/xKgCH6)  m1*m2 return invalid result, m3*m4 produce correct output. @Tschallacka

Comment: @Bob you need to include your code in your question itself (using the edit button).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra zero byte is added if the (positive) value has a first byte that is from 128 to 255.

This byte is needed so that the resulting byte are has at least one sign bit (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29)

```
BigInteger.valueOf(5L).toByteArray()
```

returns a byte array with only one byte (5).

```
BigInteger.valueOf(128L).toByteArray()
```

returns a byte array with only two bytes (0 and 128 in unsigned representation). This is to distinguish the result from

```
BigInteger.valueOf(-128L).toByteArray()
```

which returns also a byte array with two bytes (255, 128 in unsigned representation)